# Sorting MP3s by tags with bash script moves directory instead of files?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have very little knowledge of bash, but I'm trying to make a simple script that will sort MP3s into subdirectories based on album, and rename them based on track number, album and artist. My current code doesn't seem to rename and move the files correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is the current code which I made with tips from a friend who wants me to try using bash for things:

```
mkdir $2
FILES="$1"/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f..."
  ARTIST="`id3tool "$f" | grep '^Artist:' | awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { printf $i; printf " " } }'`"
  ALBUM="`id3tool "$f" | grep '^Album:' | awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { printf $i; printf " " } }'`"
  YEAR="`id3tool "$f" | grep '^Year:' | awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { printf $i; printf " " } }'`"
  TRACKNUM="`id3tool "$f" | grep '^Track:' | awk '{ print $2 }'`"
  mkdir $2/$ALBUM/
  mv $f "$TRACKNUM-$ALBUM-$ARTIST.mp3"
  mv $f $2/$ALBUM/
done
```

The first argument is an MP3 directory I'm using to test this. The second argument is the directory I want them to be moved into. When I run it, I get the testing directory moved into the target directory and none of the files are changed or put into subdirectories. Shouldn't the first mv change the name, then the second move them where I want? Is the loop selecting the directory instead of the files?

Edit: When I run it, I get the error: mv: unrecognized option '--.mp3' Even with this, it still seems to move the test directory, rather than the mp3s.

Edit2: Ok, some more testing shows that the test directory is processed rather than the files within it. How do I fix that?

Edit3: Ok, I've made some changes, and the album directories are made, but I get the mkdir error that they already exist every time after the first for each and I get

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/ResultMP3s/Album0’: File exists

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/’: File exists

mv: cannot stat ‘TestMP3s/song01.mp3’: No such file or directory

mv: cannot create directory ‘/Album0’: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

It seems that those parameters are getting set to the empty string.

```
$TRACKNUM-$ALBUM-$ARTIST.mp3 # -> --.mp3
mv $f $2/$ALBUM/ # -> mv $f $2// (if $f is a directory, this will move $f inside $2)
```

This may be due to the `for` loop. If `$f` is a directory, maybe you want

```
for f in "$1"/*; do …
```

Comment: I made some edits and tried to use mkdir because mv was giving directory does not exist errors, but now I'm getting errors like

mv: cannot stat ‘TestMP3s/song89.mp3’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot create directory ‘/Album8’: Permission denied